# webmin - can't edit mysql settings at all

Tags: webmin

New webmin user.  I have a database setup and running.  The 'MySQL Server Configuration' page provides pretty much nothing in terms of settings and the 'MySQL System Variables' page shows at the top 'Warning - Variables set on this page will be reset to their default values when MySQL is restarted. Permanent settings must be made on the MySQL Server Configuration page.' which simply goes back to the original page which doesn't let me change much of anything.

If I change settings in my.cnf manually they are all erased as soon as I restart the server.  Am I missing something here?  I need to make changes to innodb settings and I can find no way to do this!?